# No executable found for solver 'glpk' on pyomo

Tags: python, pyomo

I have an optimization model written on pyomo (Python 3.7/Ubuntu 18.04) and using

```
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory
opt = SolverFactory("gurobi")
results = opt.solve(model)
```

It works exactly as it should. However, when I try to use glpk as the solver, I get the following error:

```
ApplicationError: No executable found for solver 'glpk'.
```

Importing the package also returns an error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'glpk'
```

But when I do `conda list` on the terminal, I get this information for glpk package:

```
glpk                      4.65              he80fd80_1002    conda-forge
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It's been quite some time, but this might help future users with the same issue.

I had the same issue, while trying to run `pyomo` along with `glpk` as a solver on a debian based container image.

I was getting the following error: `Could not locate the 'glpsol' executable, which is required for solver 'glpk'. ApplicationError: No executable found for solver 'glpk'.`

After installing `glpk-utils` along with glpk, my python script executed successfully.

part of my working docker file can be found below

```
FROM python:3.10-slim-bullseye

WORKDIR /opt/app
RUN apt update && apt install -y gcc libglpk-dev glpk-utils
COPY requirements.txt /opt/app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -r requirements.txt
# requirements.txt contents (Pyomo==6.4.2 and glpk==0.4.6 among others)

COPY . .
# utilizing .dockerignore to leave files/folders out of the container image

CMD [ "python", "main.py" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

On terminal, trying running `which glpsol`.

This ought to return a path to your glpsol executable. I am guessing you won't get a result. If that's the case you need to add the location of 'glpsol' to your PATH variable. You should be able to find it by seaching for where the 'glpk' package was installed. It should be in the 'bin' folder. Hopefully.

Comment: Hi! And then what? When I run which glpsol I get the path where it is but when using spyder it says that GLPK is not available on the system

Comment: If you have also installed the glpk python package as the OP, can you ensure that you are using the same python environment in spyder?